# How to get unread count number as int for an application

Tags: android, android-launcher

Currently I am developing an android Launcher application and stuck at this point where I want to show the unread count of an application (as an unread badge) to users. But I am unable to get the number of unread messages of any application.

Comment: There is not a universal way to do this

Comment: but i can see another launcher has this features

Comment: It works differently for different launchers - see, e.g., https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger

Comment: but as i told that i m developing an launcher. i want only unread count of an app